# Unity 2D On Collision (Do Something) not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, mesh-collider

I know this question has probably been asked many times, but I'm going to ask again.For some reason, my colliders won't work. I have one on my block sprite, and another on my 'miner' sprite. When I hit play, the two start on top of each other. *(I'm not sure if this matters, it appears to make no difference.)* Each one has a Box Collider 2D. In the script assigned to one of them, it tries to see the collision.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Miner")
    {
        GameObject.Find("Miner").GetComponent<miner>().block = block;
    }
}
```

However, this script does not seem to detect the Miner sprite colliding with it. I am certain I am deriving from MonoBehavior, so it's not issue there.

Comment: How many `Miner` objects are in your Scene?

Comment: This `if (col.gameObject.name == "Miner")
    {
        GameObject.Find("Miner").GetComponent<miner>().block = block;
    }` makes little sense .. if you already have a reference to an object called `Miner` why would you use `Find` (very expensive) to again search for an object with this name? Simply use the one you already got: `col.gameObject.GetComponent<Miner>().block = block;`

Comment: You need to check the collision matrix https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do either of the GameObjects have a RigidBody2D attached to them? At least one GameObject needs to have a RigidBody in any given collision.

Comment: Ok thanks, can't try this right now, but I am sure neither had a RigidBody attached. I will try that later.

Comment: This was the issue! I gave my `Miner` sprite the RigidBody 2D component, and reset his box collider. I believe it was a mix of this and the colliders starting on top of each other, but it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Add some debug statements in your code so that you are sure this method is not running.  You should read up  [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) about Collisions in unity. Decide if these objects will be moving and set the appropriate collider. As stated above you will typically need a rigidbody.